# Setting the proxy using Selenium and Docker

Tags: python, docker, selenium, google-chrome, proxy

I have a trouble during using proxy for scraping. I use dockerized Python code and

```
selenium/standalone-chrome
```

image.
I tried something like this

```
def get_chrome_driver(proxy):
    proxy = str(proxy)
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy=%s' % proxy)
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor='http://chrome:4444/wd/hub',
        options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        )

    return driver
```

to pass the parameters but the Chrome instance seems to ignore it. I have example scraper scraping IP address from ident.me webpage and it returns my machine's IP.

Answer (score 1):

you are saving default options with this line for the driver instance

```
options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
```

you need to set your created options

```
options=chrome_options
```